# Efficient evaluation of function defined by multiple Sum

Tags: compile

I tried to make a workable example here. The problem is that it is very very slow. I must be doing something very stupid out here. Can somebody give me some clue how to evaluate this multiple sum faster. Right now it takes around 2 mins. However, for real problem I need the parameter Npol to be of the order of ~10.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
SetSystemOptions["CompileOptions"->"CompileReportExternal"->False];
DRSH=N[(94688879/10000000)*10^(-7)];
Npol=2;
nk=40;
PN=Evaluate[Table[0.0025 n,{n,1,Npol}]];
OmN=Evaluate[Table[(1.0/DRSH)^((-n+2)/Npol),{n,1,Npol}]];
fpol[n_, On_]:=(-0.38 Sqrt[4^-n])/(DRSH + 0.77 2.0^-n)/; On== OmN[[1]]
fpol[n_, On_]:=(-0.38 Sqrt[4^-n])/(DRSH + 0.77 2.0^-n) (0.77 2.0^-n-On)/(0.77 2.0^-n+On)

OverLaps1=Compile[{{k, _Integer},{n,_Real}, {m,_Real}},Exp[-0.5 Sum[If[q!= k,(fpol[q, n]-fpol[q, m])^2,0],{q,0,nk}]],CompilationTarget->"C"];
OverLaps2=Compile[{{k, _Integer},{n,_Real}, {m,_Real}},Exp[-0.5 Sum[If[q!= k,(fpol[q, n]+fpol[q, m])^2,0],{q,0,nk}]],CompilationTarget->"C"];
NpolSum=Compile[{{i, _Integer},{j, _Integer}, {k, _Integer}}, (Sum[ Sum[PN[[n]]  PN[[m]] fpol[k, OmN[[n]]]^i fpol[k, OmN[[m]]]^j Exp[-0.5 (fpol[k, OmN[[n]]]^2+ fpol[k, OmN[[m]]]^2)] ( OverLaps1[k, OmN[[n]], OmN[[m]]]+ (-1.0)^j   OverLaps2[k, OmN[[n]], OmN[[m]]]),{n,1,Npol}],{m,1,Npol}])^2,CompilationTarget->"C"];

S2Entrp=Compile[{{k, _Integer}},Sum[Sum[ ( 1/(i! j!)  )  NpolSum[i, j, k],{i,0,10}],{j,0,10}]];
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{k,S2Entrp[ k]}, {k,0, nk}],PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[Medium],Red], PlotRange-> All]//AbsoluteTiming
```

I thank you for your time.

Comment: Without looking at the code in detail, did you try replacing `Sum[...,{}]` by `Total@Table[...,{}]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One significant thing you could do is memoize the definitions for `fpol` and both `OverLaps` functions, as these are called multiple times with the same arguments.

I would also suggest creating a definition directly for `fpol[n_, OmN[[1]]]` rather than using the condition on the RHS.

I have ditched the `Compile` here, as I don't think it's giving any benefit due to all the calls to `MainEvaluate` (BTW suppressing the warnings doesn't make the problem go away...)

```
fpol[n_, OmN[[1]]] := fpol[n, OmN[[1]]] = (-0.38 Sqrt[4^-n])/(DRSH + 0.77 2.0^-n)
fpol[n_, On_] := fpol[n, On] = (-0.38 Sqrt[4^-n])/(DRSH + 0.77 2.0^-n) (0.77 2.0^-n - On)/(0.77 2.0^-n + On)

OverLaps1[k_, n_, m_] := OverLaps1[k, n, m] = Exp[-0.5 Sum[If[q != k, (fpol[q, n] - fpol[q, m])^2, 0], {q, 0, nk}]]    
OverLaps2[k_, n_, m_] := OverLaps2[k, n, m] = Exp[-0.5 Sum[If[q != k, (fpol[q, n] + fpol[q, m])^2, 0], {q, 0, nk}]]

NpolSum[i_, j_, k_] := (Sum[Sum[PN[[n]] PN[[m]] fpol[k, OmN[[n]]]^i fpol[k, OmN[[m]]]^j 
Exp[-0.5 (fpol[k, OmN[[n]]]^2 + fpol[k, OmN[[m]]]^2)] (OverLaps1[k, OmN[[n]], 
         OmN[[m]]] + (-1.0)^j OverLaps2[k, OmN[[n]], OmN[[m]]]), {n, 1, Npol}], {m, 1, Npol}])^2

S2Entrp[k_] := Sum[Sum[(1/(i! j!)) NpolSum[i, j, k], {i, 0, 10}], {j, 0, 10}]
```

I think there are further improvements that could be made, for example making `fpol` and `OverLaps` `Listable` and replacing `NpolSum` with something nifty using `Outer`, but the memoization appears to be the key to increasing the performance here.

With these changes the plot takes under half a second to create:

```
ListLogLinearPlot[Table[{k, S2Entrp[k]}, {k, 0, nk}], 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Medium], Red], PlotRange -> All] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: Yes,thank you. I also found out that Compile doesn't help here. Again thank you for the quick tip.